# TypeError: argument should be a string or a Rational instance -what is the use of *

Tags: python

I am new to python and found the below code in hacker rank

```
def product(fracs):
    t = reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, fracs)
    return t.numerator, t.denominator

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fracs = []
    for _ in range(input()):
        fracs.append(Fraction(*map(int, input().split())))
    result = product(fracs)
    print(*result)
```

I can understand all the code but when I tried to remove the * before the map func. I recived the error in the title .

What is the use of the * before the map.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \*\* (double star/asterisk) and \* (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

First of all lets concetrate on this part `input().split()`.
It takes some input from the user and splits it by whitespaces or newlines and returns a list.
So the execution of `input().split()` returns a list.
Now we use the map function which will use an int conversion for any item on that list.
So we basically get the same list but the elements are converted to integers.
The * unpacks a list.
For example if `list = [1,2,3]` then `*list = 1,2,3`.
It is probably done this way because `Fraction` doesn't expect a list as an argument.